# Keep getting this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

Tags: python, python-requests

Python keeps giving me the errror: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'.

I installed it in terminal but it still gives this error. I checked online in many websites and in stack overflow but I cannot find the solution. The closest I can come is apparently I have 2 Pythons installed? How do I know how many python versions I have installed and how do I delete all and keep just one? I'm using OS X btw.

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of `pip install requests`, use the specific version, eg for python 3.8: `pip3.8 install requests`

Comment: I would strongly consider using virtual environments, especially if you’re having these kinds of issues.

Comment: @EdWard it says requirement already satisfied

Comment: @AMC I am using PyCharm

Comment: @Sensei PyCharm is an IDE, I’m not sure how that’s related.

Comment: @AMC my bad didn't read that correctly